# How to insert a backslash into a string in Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a Python program that creates a JSON file as its output. In the JSON file there are strings, and within those strings there are quote marks. I want to escape those quote marks using a backslash, and the only way to do this would be to insert backslashes into the strings that I'm writing to this file. How can I insert a backslash into a string without it being "used up" as an escape character?

I'm trying to use the `.replace` string function to replace all instances of `"` with instances of `\"`. I've also tried replacing all instances of `"` with instances of `\\"` and `\\\"`, but none of those work.

```py
string = "\"The strings themselves are quotes, formatted like this\" - Some Guy"
string.replace("\"","\\\"") # Just doing \\" gives me an error as the backslashes cancel each other out, leaving you just three quote marks.
```

I'm trying to get the string to output the exact phrase: `\"The strings themselves are quotes, formatted like this\" - Some Guy`

Comment: I think you shouldn't bother with this as the `json` library will take care of it automatically

Comment: As ForceBru says, don't build JSON manually. Build Python data structures and then use the `json` module to convert them to JSON`.

Answer (score 2):

As advised by the previous comments, you might be looking for this:

```
import json

string = "\"The strings themselves are quotes, formatted like this\" - Some Guy"
print(json.dumps(string))
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact, that you should use the json methods for doing what you're trying to achieve: Replace returns a new string with the modified substring. Thus, your approach was correct, you just need to assign it again:

```
string = "\"The strings themselves are quotes, formatted like this\" - Some Guy"
string = string.replace("\"", "\\\"")

print(string)
```

This gives you:

> \"The strings themselves are quotes, formatted like this\" - Some Guy